# Python(Cython)の `== NULL` と `is NULL`, `return` と `return None` の違いについて

Tags: python, cython

こんにちは。Python(Cython)に関する質問です。

とあるPython(Cythonのようです)のコードの中に以下のようなif文を見つけました。

```py
    def hoge(self, fuga):
        cdef # 中略

        if self.piyo == NULL: return
            # 処理1

        if self.piyo is NULL: return None
            # 処理2
```

処理1の中には`self.piyo`を変化させるような処理は含まれていないものとします。

ここで２つのifが書かれている意味について考えています。
これは単なる重複でしょうか？それともなにか違いや意図がありますでしょうか？
Pythonに詳しくないのでやや漠然とした質問です。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: `self.piyo`がそのクラス内でどういう内容や扱いをされているものか、`hoge()`を呼び出している側で呼び出し方や戻り値の扱いをどうしているか、といった情報を追加するか、その「見つけた」という記事や資料自身へのリンクを追加した方が、助言や答えを得やすいでしょう。

Comment: 参考までに、[Differences between C and Cython expressions](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#differences-between-c-and-cython-expressions) では、`The null C pointer is called NULL, not 0 (and NULL is a reserved word)` との記載があります。また、`self.piyo is NULL` は `self.piyo is None` ではないかなと(個人的には)思っています。差し支えがなければ当該コードの URL などを追記して下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。kunifさん ここでの if文は nilガードみたいな感じで、piyoがNULLであるケースで守るためのものじゃないかと思います…。資料へのリンクは今回はなしです。すみません。metropolisさん、すばらしい洞察です。実際に `NULL` なのですが `self.piyo is None` のタイポの可能性はあると思いました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `==` と  `is` について

`xobj is yobj`
… このような式は [式 (expression) / 比較](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) の [同一性の比較](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) に記されています。

同じ実体(オブジェクト)を指しているかどうかを判定するので

- `==` での比較だと, (仮に)巨大なオブジェクト(例えば異様に長い文字列とか) だった場合, すべてが等しいか調べるために(少し)時間がかかります。`is` なら同じオブジェクトを指しているかどうかの判定なので高速です
- 同じオブジェクトなのに中身が異なることは(比較の瞬間は)ありません (なので `is` で同じなら当然 `==` と言える, はず)

なので比較の順番としては, 先に `is` で判定すべき
(NULL は Pythonでは使われてないはずなので, 「とあるコード」で定義してるのでしょう)

---

#### 戻り値に関して

以下はすべて同じものを返します

- return
- return None
- (return なしで抜けた場合)

ただ目的(意味合い？)が異なります。
例えば○○を見つけて返す処理ならば, 見つからなかった場合「存在しない」ことを示す `return None` と記述するほうが好ましい。
どれか適当に返す処理, であれば, データがなかったら `return` だけとか, 普通に処理を抜けて良いでしょう (その関数の処理内容, 目的による)。あるいは値を返す必要が全く無い場合も同様